# Displaying below an existing content worksheet

Tags: python, excel

```
def test(sheet, row=2):
    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'], index=[0])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                       'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})

    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=0, header=None, \
                 index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet, startrow=row, index=False)

    writer.save()
    writer.close()

test('aaa')
```

In the moment, this little function creates a single Excel worksheet.

**Description :**

Assume that Excel sheet exists. I want to write something else below the existing lines with the following code.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

In [4]: from openpyxl import load_workbook

In [5]: book = load_workbook("testing.xlsx")

In [6]:     df3 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': ['Chest', 'Bras', 'Braa'], 
   ...:                        'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})
   ...: 

In [8]: writer.book = book

In [9]: ws = book.get_sheet_by_name('aaa')

In [10]: writer.book
Out[10]: <openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook at 0x7f9add4e3048>

In [12]: writer.book.sheetnames
Out[12]: ['aaa']

In [13]: row = ws.max_row

In [14]: row
Out[14]: 6

In [15]: df3.to_excel(writer, "aaa", startrow=row + 2, index=False)

In [16]: writer.save()
```

This code worked almost how I wanted. It creates a new worksheet `aaa1`, and put the content of `df` at the 8th line as it should normally be. Instead of creating the new sheet `aaa1`, I want the content of `aaa1` be below the content of `aaa`. How could I fix that so that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it won't be possible if you're just using pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.  If you're open to using openpyxl for the second part I have a solution below. I used the Pandas style to format the cells in the same way the first part was formatted.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')

book = load_workbook("testing.xlsx")

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'amount': ['Chest', 'Bras', 'Braa'], 
                'income': [40000, 50000, 42000]})

writer.book = book
ws = book['aaa']

row = ws.max_row

#best way to replicate your insertion of 2 blank rows which 
ws.append(tuple())
ws.append(tuple())

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df3, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

#a quick way to give you the same style as you get with the first part
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=row +3, max_col=2, max_row=row +3):
    for cell in row:
        cell.style = 'Pandas'

writer.save()
```

With the desired output:
[image: Excel Output]